# Always exponential growth when multiplication factor is greater than 1

Tags: exponential-function

Let an exponential function take the form
$$y=a \cdot b^x$$
I know if *a* is greater than $0$ and *b* is greater than $1$, this is called exponential growth.

What if *a* is less than $0$ and *b* is greater than $1$?  Is this still exponential growth?

Comment: Yes it is, in the sense that the absolute value is growing.

Comment: I’ve heard it being called exponential decay in the sense that the value decreases, but it *might* also be referred to as negative exponential growth in the sense the values become more negative (increasing absolute value). Names aren’t often assigned to the $a < 0$ case though.

Answer (score 1):

When $b<1$, this is known as “exponential decay” and is a common term as it is used to model many systems. The case $a<0$ is less commonly used and doesn’t have a generally agreed upon name, I’ve heard it called exponentially decreasing though.